# Solving a linear in-homogeneous constant coefficient recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have the following homework problem:

a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n-1</sub> + 12a<sub>n-2</sub> + 5(2)<sup>n</sup>

The problem states to find the general solution to the recurrence relation, as well as to find and solve for the particular solution.

I know how to solve for the homogeneous part (roots -3 & 4):

a<sub>n</sub><sup>H</sup> = K<sub>1</sub>(-3<sup>n</sup>) + K<sub>2</sub>(4<sup>n</sup>)

Likewise, I know from my textbook that:
a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>n</sub><sup>H</sup> + a<sub>n</sub><sup>P</sup>

However, I am stuck trying to find what the general form of the particular solution is. I understand that this should be a relatively easy problem, but I am completely lost and would appreciate any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

WLOG set $a_m=b_m+c2^m$

Compare the coefficients of $2^n$ to find

$$5=c-c/2-12c/4\implies c=?$$

Comment: How did you compare the coefficients of 2^n?

Comment: @RichardMcCormick, If $$a_m=b_m+c2^m,$$  $$ a_n=?,a_{n-1}=?, a_{n-2}=?$$